# How to enable intl extension in MAC M1 for php version 8.x?

Tags: php, macos

My PHP version is `PHP 8.0.3`. I am trying to enable php intl extension for an Application.

```
php -v

PHP 8.0.3 (cli) (built: Mar 11 2021 09:04:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

I am getting nothing after give command

```
php --modules | grep intl
```

I have also upgrade php version using brew by below command

```
brew upgrade php         
Warning: php 8.0.7 already installed
```

I am getting below error when trying to run cakephp application

```
cake_4 % bin/cake bake                       
PHP Fatal error:  You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cake_4/config/requirements.php on line 31
```

How can I install and load intl extension in brew ?

Comment: intl should come bundled with PHP, have you checked your `php.ini` to see that the extension isn't disabled?

Comment: I have enable intl in ini file , not got this error                            
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_intl.dll' (tried: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/php_intl.dll (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/php_intl.dll, 9): image not found), /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/php_intl.dll.so (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/php_intl.dll.so, 9):